# Prevent processes from reading userspace

Tags: linux, memory, security, centos, user-accounts

I was trying to read and write values from a process with a program (ceserver, part of the CheatEngine project) which both ran in user-space (without root). I didn't expect it to work, however unfortunately it did, I could even manipulate the memory (e.g manipulating the text inside the editor etc.). I wanted to ask if that's a security leak and if, how fatal it is and how to prevent that.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the linux site

Comment: You mean it doesn't have anything to do with user configuration?
Well, you're probably right, I'm removing it from here. ty for the .suggestion

Comment: No, I mean they are to know how it is going to interact. I'm not sure what program you're talking about or if you built it yourself. If you built it yourself they'll likely be more helpful.

Comment: You may get an answer here but you know that you're going to be working on Linux and they specialize in Linux

Comment: No, but it's not this much used, I'm using ceserver, which is part of the CheatEngine project. But it uses nothing special so even other programms like scanmem should be able to do that.

Comment: I don't know never used it but that's definitely information you should include in your question

Comment: ok, thank you I'm going to reopen this at the Linux site, including your suggestion.

Comment: @The19thFighter: If you're going to re-open then delete this one. Cross-posting is not allowed.

Comment: You can wait a bit. Depending on how mission critical it is. Maybe a few hours. Giving SU guys a chance to answer :p it also prevents unnecessary cross site questions

Comment: Don't worry. I'm just waiting to copy that.
k, I'll just wait first, and meanwhile, edit it.

Comment: @The19thFighter Just as a followup did you ever get an answer?

Comment: I didn't post it somewhere else.